# Difference between LS coupling and jj coupling

Tags: angular-momentum, atomic-physics

In the LS coupling the total angular momentum is given by 
$$J=L+S$$
where $S=\sum s_i$ and $L=\sum l_i$

whereas the in jj coupling is given by
$$J=\sum (s_i + l_i)$$
here $s_i$ is the spin and $l_i$ is the orbital angular momentum.

why this too angular momentum  are different ?

Comment: Since perturbation theory is based on making small changes to known systems, perturbations must be applied in the correct order, i.e. in order of decreasing severity. That's why we use operators, which have a non-zero communtation. Or as I once have been told: It makes a difference if you first open then window and then stick out your head, or if you first stick out your head and then open the window.

Comment: So you are saying  that they are equal but the problem is in use them in perturbation theory?

Comment: Semoi's comment is incorrect. The two operators are equal. The difference is that the different internal angular momenta don't commute, and you need to choose which ones to diagonalize simultaneously with the total angular momentum.

Comment: Could your clarify a little more because i am not understanding what you are saying